# i-NEX Not Installing on UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: command-line

Can anybody offer a working solution on how to install iNEX monitoring tool system/hardware information application on my Ubuntu 18.04?
I have tried several different things from different websites.
I keep getting errors. Why is this so hard? Why do I have to enter my password after every command? Can't there be an easier way? Windows does it, why can't Ubuntu and Linux do it?

I'm partially blind, and all I want to do is load a simple app to get some simple answers. I could have taken my machine apart and put it back together in the time that I've spent researching this topic and entering several lines of text for every suggestion.

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using, and to include as much detail about the 'so many errors' as possible. Complete terminal output would be best. Yes, there probably are easier ways, but you chose non-Ubuntu (PPA) software, which can sometimes be complicated. The ranting is not appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I-Nex currently doesn't have a Bionic Release so you will have to use the Zesty repository:

```
sudo -s

echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/i-nex-development-team/daily/ubuntu zesty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

exit
```

I-Nex requires the Gambas runtimes, so if you don't have them, you will have to add that repository also (it is up-to-date):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gambas-team/gambas3
```

Now update your sources and install:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install gambas3-dev gambas3-gb-image gambas3-gb-qt5 gambas3-gb-form gambas3-gb-desktop gambas3-gb-form-stock -y

sudo apt install i-nex
```

Comment: Adding the gambas PPA worked a treat. I installed using the I-Nex .deb so needed to perform a 'sudo apt -f install' to find and install the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

***Installing i-Nex on Ubuntu***

To install i-Nex on Ubuntu, do the following:

**Step 1.** Open a terminal (in Unity use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keys);

**Step 2.** If you do not already have it, add the program repository with this command or use this tutorial;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: i-nex-development-team / stable
```

**Step 3.** (optional) If you do not already have it, also add the program runtime repository with command below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: nemh / gambas3
```

**Step 4.** Update the APT with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 5.** Now install the program with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install i-nex
```

***How to install i-Nex manually or in other distros***

For those who could not install with the above procedure, do not want to add the repository or want to try to install in another Debian-based distribution, you can pick up the DEB file from the program on that link and install it manually (double-clicking on it).

But remember! By choosing this type of installation, you will not receive any updates to the program.

Ready! Now, when you want to start the program, type i-nex in the Dash (or in a terminal, followed by the TAB key).

***Uninstalling i-Nex on Ubuntu and derivatives***

To uninstall i-Nex in Ubuntu and its derivatives, do the following:

**Step 1.** Open a terminal;

**Step 2.** Uninstall the program, using the commands below;

```
sudo apt-get remove i-nex --auto-remove
```

Comment: Are you sure those PPAs cover the version of Ubuntu that John is using?

Comment: @user535733 Both are old PPAs and doesn't this look like a very sloppy copy/paste from somewhere else?

Comment: Hello Sergio, Thank you very much for the quick response. I will try this right away and let you know. Thanks again for your help! John